# Detect if javascript is enabled in a winforms/mfc embedded browser

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control

I have a native (windows) application that has an embedded web browser. Currently I'm invoking a javascript function from the backend (c++/c#). However, if javascript is disabled this fails and I'd like to provide a fallback mechanism. Is there a way to determine if javascript is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IE Web Control, you can simply force JavaScript on. Please refer to the following interfaces, which your host has to implement:

- IDocHostUIHandler
- IDocHostShowUI
- IInternetSecurityManager
- IServiceProvider

Another approach would be for your HTML page to query the window.external object and call a method on it, which you implement in your host, which sets a flag to true. Not being called would mean the JavaScript was not executed.

Comment: The IInternetSecurityManager was just what I needed. I found a nice explination of how to implement it here... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/c6b9bfbb-12b4-47f8-8dda-c89646358f52

Answer (score 0):

Wow, using web browser under mfc is really pain in the ass, you can do it by getting the [IInternetSecurityManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537130(v=vs.85)), and check if is enabled to execute javascript by current policy, if user select to disable javascript on his IE, you will need to overwrite the value in the registry.

```
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetSecurityManager, NULL, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IInternetSecurityManager, (void**)&pSecurityMgr);

    int policy = URLPOLICY_ALLOW;

    hr = pSecurityMgr->ProcessUrlAction(L"http://www.google.com", URLACTION_SCRIPT_RUN,
    (BYTE*)&policy, sizeof(policy), NULL, 0, PUAF_TRUSTED, 0);
```

if hr = S_FALSE, javascript execution is disabled...